# What is the type="prob" in the predict function?

Tags: r

**Type parameter of the predict() function**

What does the type="prob" argument in the predict function do?
My is a sample of my code:

```
rf <- randomForest( Creditability ~. , data=train)      
rf2 <- randomForest( Creditability ~. , data=train2)      


prediction <- predict(rf, test)
prob_prediction <- predict(rf,test,type="prob")

prediction2 <- predict(rf2, test2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation (http://ugrad.stat.ubc.ca/R/library/randomForest/html/predict.randomForest.html):

> **type**: one of response, prob. or votes, indicating the type of output:
>   predicted values, matrix of class probabilities, or matrix of vote
>   counts. class is allowed, but automatically converted to "response",
>   for backward compatibility.